# What is usually written at the end of a slides presentation to imply "Thanks for listening"?

Tags: usage, phrase-requests

I've seen this phrase a couple of times but couldn't read the Kanji so I don't remember it.

Otherwise, what phrase would be good to include in the last slide to imply "Thanks for listening!"?

For example, after giving a presentation about project that you are working on, after finishing talking at a seminar.

Comment: Err, that is an *extremely* vague question.  Power point by whom? marketing guys? scientists? teachers?  I'm afraid this is not really a good question…

Comment: Axioplase’s comment refers to revision 1 of the question.  The question after the edit (revision 2) seems ok.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the most common one around is `ご清聴ありがとうございました`.

Comment: Yep, I think that is the one.

Comment: Beat me to it!  ;).  Note that the reading is せいちょう.  However, there is another せいちょう that means nearly the same thing:  静聴.  While 静聴 simply means "quietly listening", 清澄 has more of a respectful nuance to it.

Comment: @sawa, If I use 0% full page zooming, your text is jarbled.  If I use 10% full page zooming, your text is normal Japanese....  Weird, huh?

Comment: @op, you can say ~てくれてありがとう, generally, to thank people for favors they have done for you.  ~て represents a て-form verb.  In this case, 聞いてくれてありがとう could be okay, but ご清聴ありがとうございました is better.  せいちょう means "attention" and the ご which precedes it is honorific language.  I think you sound like Golem from Lord of the Rings if you fail to use honorific language when it is necessary.  Anyway, noun+ありがとう means, 'thanks for that'.  You would be saying, in an unGolemlike way: 'Thank you for your attention.'